# Symbols ok and no_camera_permission cannot be resolved

Tags: java, android

I'm not able to resolve symbols "ok" and "no_camera_permission".I have enclosed my screenshots of the errors below
[image: error 1]

[image: error2]

please help me what to do

Answer (score 0):

`strings.xml` file.
You need assign this string.

```
<string name="ok">YourString</string>
<string name="permission_camera_rationale">YourString</string>
```